# Mock an api function call inside of a route without actually calling it

Tags: javascript, api, mocking, jestjs

I've got a route in my api which calls another server and I've ran into a problem where I can't test, mock a resolved value, for that another server call. The unit test seems to always call the other server no matter how I approach this.

```
    let iAgent: PartialMock<InternalAgent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        iAgent = {
            extend: jest.fn()
        };
    });
```

```
if(iAgent.extend) {
    iAgent.extend.mockResolvedValue({});
}

const r = await request.post('/api/v1/webhooks/extend')
.send({
    id: 1
});
expect(r.status).toEqual(200);
expect(iAgent.extend).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

and inside my actual route it calls this everytime:

```
await iAgent.extend();
```

and fails on this line as the other server is not running and I get a message of refused connection. Appearently the `iAgent.extend` function does not even get called once, yet manages to return a rejection.

So by all means I believe it shouldn't call the actual function in my route and skip it, falling back to my resolved value in the test if I understand correctly, however that's not the case and I'm not sure how to continue.

Oh and just to be clear about the `if` check for my `mockResolvedValue`, that is just to avoid the strict null checks in my config for now. But I have logged inside of the conditional and it does mock the value

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy did I miss this. The problem here was that my routes were using the same class instance throughout all of the app and my unit test was trying to mock another instance of it - that is why the resolved value wasn't used in the route function when calling the other server.

So just by using the same instance of that agent class I was able to get my mocked value easily